# Usage of the word "dis"

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context

On [twitter](https://twitter.com/YouTube/status/806645526364061696):

> New phone, who dis?

I found **dis** is an informal word meaning *speak disrespectfully to or criticize.* and it needs an object adhering, like *I don't like her dissing my friends.* But the grammar doesn't fit and the meaning is strange to me, so what's the usage of dis here?

Comment: "Who's this?", perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"New phone, who dis?" is an internet meme that originated sometime around 2014. "dis" in this instance, can be read as poor spelling (or [textspeak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMS_language)) of the word "this". The meme generally uses the following format:

> A: [Asks B for a favor]
>
> B: new phone who dis

Literally, "new phone who dis" means, "I got a new phone [and therefore lost my contacts], who is this?" However, in the context of the meme, “new phone who dis” is a way of indicating that one would prefer to ignore a message.

http://memearchives.tumblr.com/post/127423253414/meme-explanation-new-phone-who-dis

Answer (score 3):

In your example

> dis

is slang-ish for

> this

just as

> dat = that
>   deeze = these
>   doze = those